# Analyze frequency of chars in string

Tags: c

I'm trying to build program that analyzes the frequency of letters in string, and then switch the most frequently occurring letter with the second most frequently occurring letter.

So it supposed to take few steps:

1. Detection of the most high frequency char show in the string
2. Detection of the most second frequency char show in the string
3. Switch between the letters
4. Print it

My idea was to make an array with all the letters, and then use loop to pass over the string, compare it with the array and then — I don't know how to proceed from here.

So when the input is like this:

- **donald trump will make america great again**

the output after the algorithm will be:

- don**e**ld trump will m**e**ke **e**meric**e** gr**ae**t **e**g**e**in

I'm trying to write the program but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: This looks like an HW problem. Please show a good faith effort in solving this when posting here.

Comment: @kabanus - HW is hardware, takes a while to determine that you mean homework :(

Comment: @KevinDTimm depends what you do in life :) Thanks for elaborating.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an array where each cell corresponds to a letter in the alphabet. Then, you may traverse the string you have and whenever you see an alphabetical character you may update the value in the cell corresponding to that letter. Then, you may just find the two most frequent characters by going through that array. Finally, you can traverse the string, replacing the relevant characters as you described.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way will be :**
  Use **Hashing** for getting max and second max frequency and character

**For Change of characters:**
 you can create a **parsing function** to parse and change that character every time it appears while parsing or printing. I hope this will help you